# How effective in terms of conversions is a logged out user profile creation?

Tags: signup-signon, profile, onboarding, novice-users

I am designing a responsive website (app in phase 2) whose target audience will be 25-45yo parents/educators. We want users to be able to browse the website without login barriers but ultimately we also want them to create their own profile with children's age, tastes, and preferences so we can tailor their experience and give them better recommendations.

My idea for a smooth approach is:
As soon as they search for something, cache their search settings in a temporary profile page and ask users to Sign Up if they want to Save those settings + if they want to unlock other types of settings on the same page (all this with nice explanatory microscopy). This way users will sign up only when they want more benefits, which I think it's a non-intrusive and nice experience for the user. Plus, they would have already a half created profile and will slowly learn how to use it, which I think is good for less tech-savvy users.

Now, my question is:

**How effective in terms of conversions is this auto-created half-profile approach compared to the classic onboarding little questionnaire + Sign Up page?**

I'm especially looking for some data/researches on the topic, also any opinions would be really helpful, thank you!

Comment: Ironically, this seems to be what Stackexchange just did with me. Is there a name for this "pattern"?

Answer (score 1):

The best term I've come across that could describe this pattern is [Considered Signup](https://blog.innertrends.com/fast-signup-vs-considered-signup/).
The article referenced here does contain some data although perhaps not representable to your situation.

I'm personally all for a 'considered signup'. I believe an initial signup could potentially block users from using your product. It's also partially why ecommerce sites added a guest checkout option.
It's as if you're offering your user a demo. Your showing your user the value of your product.

I think you might be interested in what [Intercom](https://blog.intercom.com/) writes about. They have quite a few great articles about user onboarding.